# Can I dim lights by making amount of power smaller?

Tags: light, studio-lighting, power

Can I dim lights by making amount of power smaller? I'm using Falcon Eyes LH-ESB6060K lighting kit.
I thought, It should be possible, but is it safe? And is there any other way to dim it?

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR ANSWERING! Unfortunately, the box says that it is not compatible with "dimming circuits", so just thanks for trying to help me, and I hope someone else like me would find this helpful in his/her doings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the descriptions I found on Google e.g. from [Benel](http://www.benel.eu/webshop/continuous-and-videolight/continuous-lighting-kits/falcon-eyes-daylight-set-lh-esb6060k-8x40w.html)

> The Falcon Eyes LH-ESB6060K Continuous Daylight Set contains two standard lamp holders each with a foldable 50x50cm softbox, two diffuse cloths (50x50cm), eight 40W energy saving spiral lamps with a power comparability of 200W each and two i-2501/B light stands (2.5m).
>
> This set is ideal for product photography, portrait photography and videography and is suitable for both, beginner and experienced photographers and videographers. This set is easy to mount and allows you to create a soft and even light around a person or object. The softboxes are pre mounted, making the set easy to assemble.
>
> Additional Information about the Falcon Eyes LH-ESB6060K Continuous Daylight Set
>
> If you wish to lower your light output, it is possible to purchase and replace your 40W spiral lamps with 28W spiral lamps. These can be found in the optional accessories tab below. Alternatively, up to seven of the 40W lamps can be screwed loose in order to minimize your light output.

that would be 'No', they are not dimmable - instead you swap to lower-wattage bulbs, or remove some. If they were dimmable, no doubt they would be keen to sell that option to you.

Most energy-saving fluorescents are not dimmable.
You can get them, but they would not have an accurate colour-temperature - see this [eBay search](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/dimmable-cfl) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your set is a basic one. Most likely you can not dim thoose lights, but this depends on the type of light you have on it.

To dim the light you need to turn off 1, 2 or 3 lamps. If you do not have a specific switch for it, unscrew them.

Another method to dim the lights are moving away your lightbox.

---

Playing with an AC power regulator potentially will cause your lights to flicker and reduce the life of them. You can use another type of screwable lights on thoose sockets.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I dim lights by making amount of power smaller?

**Possibly**. This light appears to be simple lamp (no controlling electronics in the lamp — basically, a glorified table lamp). If that's the case, then **if and only if your CFL bulbs are dimmable**, you can use a CFL-compatible dimmer to control this lamp.

Again, non-dimmable CFL bulbs should not be used with dimmers: [they present a fire hazard](https://www.energycircle.com/blog/2011/09/21/why-you-should-never-use-non-dimmable-cfls-dimmer-switches):

> CFLs have less resistance than incandescent bulbs, which means that the floodgates are opened when they are exposed to the electrical fluctuations that a dimmer sends, and they actually can consume up to 5x the current as when they're not connected to a dimmer (and that's when the dimmer is set to max). This overheats the bulb and can actually cause it to light on fire. Bad news.

If you are using CFL bulbs, you need to use dimmable CFLs, in conjunction with a CFL-compatible dimmer switch. Also, you need to make sure the dimmer switch is rated for the power of the lights it is controlling. Each of the Falcon Eyes fixtures you are using comes with (qty 4) 40W CFL bulbs. Thus, the fixture's lights draw 160W total, so the dimmer for each light stand must be rated for at least 160 watts.

---

Alternately, you might be able to replace the CFLs with incandescent bulbs (if you are able to obtain them at a reasonable price), which would allow you to use a standard rheostat or triac-controlled dimmer, **BUT** before doing so, you need to determine if the lamp is rated for higher-wattage incandescent light bulbs.

Comment: I found later that the box says:Do not use in dimming circuits

Answer (score -4):

You need a dimmer - like this 1000W version from Impact.

https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?A=details&O=&Q=&c3api=1876%2C65681218442%2C%2C&gclid=Cj0KCQiA38jRBRCQARIsACEqIet9RZXxpP48UgZOp-efi6czCJmM0Rze1G227LEqqwz783mF5bID6WgaAiUFEALw_wcB&is=REG&pcur=CAD&sku=755346

Comment: Ummm... So that decreases the power amount, right? And I'm not in America, so is that available somewhere else also?

Comment: down-vote because this answer is not helpful in what StackExchange considers helpful. Product recommendation is off-topic because it is too narrow and ages fast. I like the answer though, so could you elaborate on use of dimmers and limitations? probably based on your experience or someone's experience

Comment: Besides this, a power regulator will potentially make the lights flicker instead of diming.

Comment: This is a rheostat dimmer. It is not suitable for dimming CFL lights. Furthermore, if the CFL lights in the fixture are not dimmable CFL lights, [there is a potential fire hazard using non-dimmable CFLs in a dimmer](https://www.energycircle.com/blog/2011/09/21/why-you-should-never-use-non-dimmable-cfls-dimmer-switches).